# What are the oxygen requirements for an IFR flight eastbound on V520 from DBS VORTAC in an unpressurized aircraft at the MEA?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, faa-knowledge-test

IFR written test question by the FAA. Available answers:

1. The required minimum crew must be provided and use supplemental oxygen for that part of the flight of more than 30 minutes, and the passengers must be provided supplemental oxygen.
2. The required minimum crew must be provided and use supplemental oxygen.
3. The required minimum crew must be provided and use supplemental oxygen for that part of the flight of more than 30 minutes.

Apparently the correct answer is 2? MEA is 15,300FT... I don't understand why passengers don't need oxygen. [image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The MEA is over 14000, so crew members must be using oxygen *at all times*. This means that both 1 and 3 are wrong. By process of elimination, 2 must be the correct answer.

A *better* answer to this would be "The required minimum crew must be provided and use supplemental oxygen, and the passengers must be provided supplemental oxygen." But answer 2 is not wrong, it is just incomplete. When choosing between an incomplete answer and a wrong answer on a multiple choice test, you need to pick the incomplete answer.

Comment: @user2605553 this is yet another case of FAA trickery I described in my answer to your other question 

Comment: And the extra info ("eastbound" - so westbound won't be an issue?) is also meant to confuse you. Standard multiple-choice question construction.

Comment: @JonCuster Westbound from DBS on V520 has a lower MEA and actually would change the answer in this case.

Comment: IIRC, there was a question recently about whether there were *any* commercial flights with passengers where passengers normally required oxygen during regular (not emergency) flight. And on that basis - i.e., it hardly ever happens, especially as high as 520 because few planes fly that high in the first place - the "passenger" part is basically irrelevant.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact It may be irrelevant *commercially*, but GA flights can and do go above 15000 feet in unpressurized aircraft.

Comment: @Chris True. The question is how often do they do that *with passengers* and *without pressurization*.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact The answer is *sometimes*. ;) It's basically the mission that turbocharged unpressurized airplanes were designed for.

Answer (score 0):

The thin air at 15,300 feet isn't dangerous to healthy individuals -- mountain climbers routinely climb summits higher than that without supplemental oxygen -- but it really messes up your decision-making.  The crew need to be thinking clearly, so they need to be on oxygen, but the passengers are't making any important decisions.

Comment: Not disagreeing with your explanation, however passengers are required to have supplemental oxygen above 15,000 ft. As pointed out in the answer by @Chris the correct answer in the FAA exam (#2) was an incomplete statement. Likely a trick question, designed to catch someone who remembered the 15,000 limit for passengers and thus assumed answer #2 was wrong and went with answer #1 because they didn't remember the 14,000 ft. limit for pilots.